Apache Camel Rest DSL OpenAPI generator
Based on the examples, I created the following REST endpoints in the Apache Camel Spring Boot project and published the OpenAPI specification:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <restConfiguration component="servlet" apiContextPath="/api-docs">
        </restConfiguration>

        <rest path="/say">
            <get path="/hello">
                <to uri="direct:hello"/>
            </get>
            <get path="/bye" consumes="application/json">
                <to uri="direct:bye"/>
            </get>
            <post path="/bye">
                <to uri="mock:update"/>
            </post>
        </rest>
    </camelContext>

</beans>

Currently, when I access the following URL: /api/api-docs, I receive the following response:
"openapi" : "3.0.0"

From which it is clear that the OpenAPI specification is being generated in version 3.0
I am using Apache Camel 4.9.0-SNAPSHOT.
Is it possible to configure Camel to generate an OpenAPI specification in version 2.0?

Support for 2.0 was deprecated in Camel 4.4.0 and was removed in 4.5.0. https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4x-upgrade-guide-4_4.html#_camel_openapi_java_and_camel_rest_openapi
